# Flutter Stepper Widget Showing can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function'

Tags: flutter, dart, stepper

i learn from a youtube ,create Stepper [Flutter Tutorial - How To Use Stepper Widget | The Right Way | Multi-Step Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpQTNW5woVI&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com)

```
         controlsBuilder: (context, {onStepContinue, onStepCancel}) {
                  final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;

                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text(isLastStep ? "Confirm" : "NEXT"),
                            onPressed: onStepContinue,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 12),
                        if (currentStep != 0)
                          Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              child: Text("BACK"),
                              onPressed: onStepCancel,
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
```

full code here [Github Stepper](https://github.com/MarioCastle/Stepper.git)

keep showing this ..make me confuse can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function'  how to solve this problem ?? thank guy`

Answer (score 0):

You can get `onStepCancel` and `onStepContinue` from `ControlDetails`.

```dart
controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
  // details.onStepCancel; //you can have it here
  // details.onStepContinue
  final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(isLastStep ? "Confirm" : "NEXT"),
            onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 12),
        if (currentStep != 0)
          Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("BACK"),
              onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  );
},
```

And try to skip old-tuitorial, better will be following flutter.dev

Comment: controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
                  // details.onStepCancel; //you can have it here
                  details.onStepContinue;
                  details.onStepCancel;

                  // details.onStepContinue
Trying to add this because onPressed: `onStepCancel`  & `onStepContinue` shows error

Comment: can you try to upgrade your flutter